# Values are correct and within range but still sends an email

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a Upper Limit and Lower Limit on my spreadsheet responses that I input towards the right of my responses. The limits are both on F2 and G2. F2 is Lower Limit and G2 is Upper Limit. The code is using the function onFormSubmit and it has an `MailApp.sendEmail` function that will send an email in case someone enters a figure that is out of the limit.

What I do not understand that, the value that I read when the form is submitted is actually within the range but it still triggers an email.

I have tried this code specifically on a brand new form and spreadsheet and it did not have any problem.

```java
function onFormSubmit(e){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Responses 1");

  var speedUL = sheet.getRange("K2").getValue(); //250V
  var speedLL = sheet.getRange("L2").getValue(); //207V

  //var speedUL= parseInt(activess.getRange("K2").getValue()); //250V
  //var speedLL = parseInt(activess.getRange("L2").getValue()); //207V

  var speed1 = parseInt(e.values[2]);
  if((speed1 >= speedUL) || (speed1 <= speedLL)){

    console.log('SpeedUL: '+speedUL);
    console.log('SpeedLL: '+speedLL);
    console.log('Speed1: '+speed1);

  var template1 = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("speed1");
  template1.speed1 = speed1;

  MailApp.sendEmail("someone@gmail.com ",
                    "Out of Range Notification Speed of VSD",
                    "",
                    {htmlBody : template1.evaluate().getContent()});

  }else
  { 
    return;
  }
}
```

This is the test script that I am trying to do. With this code, I'm getting this

`Error
Aug 26, 2019, 5:24:29 PM
TypeError: Cannot call method "getRange" of null.
    at onFormSubmit(Code:7)`

Line 7 refers to `var speedUL = sheet.getRange("K2").getValue();`

Comment: Update: When I tried on the live form itself and entering the same exact value. I am not getting the email. It seems random.

Comment: `getValue()` may be giving you something other than a number. try checking its `typeof`, or force it to a number with `+` or `parseInt`

Comment: @sinaraheneba - I have to include a ``Logger.e`` right? I tried this logging method it didn't give me any output even upon form submit.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're talking about. If you mean logging for the sake of finding your bug, `Logger.log()` or `console.log()` both work.

Comment: I will try this out. Can't be sure if it will find the problem as the problem seems pretty random. I tried myself to send a test value of exact figures and it didn't trigger the email.

Comment: Don't try to test the function as a whole. Test piece-by-piece until you find exactly what part is causing problems; chances are, that will be enough to fix it, and if not, bring it here and it should be much easier for someone else to provide the answer

Comment: I will, thank you.

Comment: @sinaraheneba i have tried the possible solutions given by you and other users. However the problem is random and I got an email again that is within range when I am not supposed to. I have tried ``typeof`` and I am getting it as a number.

Comment: Your current error simply means `sheet` is `null` probably because you got the sheet name `"Responses 1"` wrong. But it's better to ask a new question for a new error.

Comment: The sheet name is correct and I have rename it multiple times. I even tried using the ID of the sheet. @TheMaster

The problem still persists, the script randomly triggers an email even when it is within range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Probable Cause:

- `getRange()` is called upon spreadsheet class (`ss`) and not on the sheet class (`sheet`). This usually means value of G2 and F2 of the first sheet is taken and not the specied sheet.
- `e.values` is array of strings. Implicit conversion takes place when numbers are compared with strings. This is probably not the cause of your issue, but still needs to be addressed.

#### Solution:

- Call `getRange()` on the sheet or specify the sheet name, when calling `getRange()` on spreadsheet.
- Use explicit type conversion of `e.value` to number.

#### Snippet:

```
var temperature = Number(e.values[1]);
var temperatureUCL = ss.getRange("H3 Reponses!G2").getValue();
//or
var temperatureUCL = sheet.getRange("G2").getValue();
```

#### References:

- [Spreadsheet#getRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getRange(String))
- [Sheet#getRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangea1notation)

Comment: Got it, I'll have that and give a go. Thank you.

Comment: I tried using ``sheet.getRange("G2").getValue();`` it doesn't actually trigger any email at all. When I changed to ``ss.getRange("G2").getValue();``, it started sending emails back. I am not how it is related but apparently using ``sheet`` does not actually get proper values too.

Comment: @D3FT Log it. `Logger.log(sheet.getRange("G2").getValue())`

Comment: I did try but my logs are always empty even upon Form submission.

Comment: @D3FT use `console.log()` and view>stackdriver logs/ executions

Comment: It didn't work for me. Both didn't show any output.

Comment: Finally it worked for console.log. When I tried ``var temperatureUCL = ss.getRange("H3 Responses!G2").getValue();`` it returns range not found. When I tried `` var tempUCL = sheet.getRange("G2").getValue();`` it also gives me range not found. @TheMaster

Comment: @D3FTY You say above that it's returning a number type (for `temperature`, I suppose, but as I stated, you want to check what is being returned by `getValue()`, not the event object) , but here you state that it's returning an invalid range error. Which is it? Try to figure out why your range is invalid (same as last time: break down your problem to component pieces and figure out what's not working); update your question to provide a sample sheet if you're stuck on that.

Comment: @D3FT You aren't showing me the error code. That error is probably not because of the line you're showing. Check line number. [Search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-apps-script%5D+range+not+found). Also Try renaming your sheet to something simple like `response1`

Comment: Edited the question. I have done with ``ss.getRange("Cell Position").getValue();``, the values I got was what was in the cell. So there is no way that the program actually sends the email, but yesterday I got an email saying its out of range when the value that was keyed in by a user is well within the specified range.